# Rooting with value and set as default into select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Index view who have one button one for create and other for edit

That index have a dataTable who loads depending of selected value of `<select>` like:

```
 function cargarCatalogo() {
   apiService.get("/api/Catalogos/Get/", null,
     function(res) {
       $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
       $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];

       $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
     }, errorCatalogo);
 }


 // Here I load datatable depending of selected value
 $scope.filtro = function(selected) {
   $("#tabla_catalogos").dataTable().fnDestroy();
   apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID);

   var table = $('#tabla_catalogos').DataTable({
     searching: true,
     dom: 'ftpB',
     autoWidth: false,
     buttons: [
       //'excelHtml5', 'csv', 'print'
     ],
     paging: true,
     select: {
       style: 'single'
     },
     info: false,
     ordering: true,
     "processing": true,
     ajax: {
       method: 'GET',
       url: "../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID,
       dataSrc: '',
       beforeSend: function(request) {
         request.setRequestHeader("Version", $scope.usuario.Version);
         request.setRequestHeader("Origen", 'Web');
       }
     },
     columns: [{
       data: 'Catalogo',
       visible: false,
       searchable: false
     }, {
       data: 'Codigo'
     }, {
       data: 'ID',
       visible: false,
       searchable: false
     }, {
       data: 'Nombre'
     }, {
       data: 'Padre',
       visible: false,
       searchable: false
     }],
     pageLength: 10,
     language: {
       "emptyTable": "No se encontraron registros",
       "zeroRecords": "No encontraron coincidencias",
       "search": "Buscar: "
     }
   });

   $("#eliminar").prop('disabled', true);
   $("#editar").prop('disabled', true);
   table.on('select', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
     $("#eliminar").prop('disabled', false);
     $("#editar").prop('disabled', false);
   });
   table.on('deselect', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
     $("#eliminar").prop('disabled', true);
     $("#editar").prop('disabled', true);
   });
 };
```

As you can see it set a select default value as: `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];` so when Index load it always have first option selected

So my view is something like:
[image]

When I click add or edit it loads `root.detallesRegistros`, but now when I add  something it run this function:

```
 $scope.insertar = function() {
        var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/"
        apiService.post(url, null,
          function(response) {
            bootbox.alert("Success!");
            $state.go("root.catalogosgenericos");
          }
          });
      }

    }
```

As you can see it redirects to `catalogosgenericos` with  `$state.go("root.catalogosgenericos");` which is my Index , and it loads selected value first option of select because I have `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];`,  that I want is to set that select value depending of item I added, for example if I clic "modelos" then click Add, when I submit new "modelos" I want it to return me to `catalogosgenericos` view but with "modelos" as selected value, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the new selected value as state parameter.

```
$state.go("root.catalogosgenericos", {param: param});
```

In your first function check for the state params and assign the value into $scope.selected. Since you don't have a state param initially, you can assign it to get the first element of the array.

Comment: I do it, and it load my option but when it get predefined selected it just don´t show values of data table. Why can be wrong there?